# Want to load user profiles onto tableView using Firebase and GeoFire

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview, geofire

I've been working on a ios App that uses Firebase and GeoFire. I was able to store user coordinates using GeoFire into firebase. I am now trying to load the user details onto a tableview with GeoFire but have been unsuccessful. Without Geofire I was able to load all the user details onto the table, but now it just shows a blank table. Would someone please give me some pointers?

```
var myQuery: GFQuery?
var geoFireRef: DatabaseReference?
var geoFire: GeoFire?
var user = Auth.auth().currentUser

var filteredUsers = [Users]()

var users = [Users]()

var isSearching = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    geoFireRef = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://yala-2018.firebaseio.com/").child("user_locations")

    geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geoFireRef!)

    let userLat = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "current_latitude") as! String
    let userLong = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "current_longitude") as! String
     let location:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(Double(userLat)!), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(Double(userLong)!))

     myQuery = geoFire?.query(at: location, withRadius: 100)

    myQuery?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key, location) in

        if key != Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {

        // print("KEY:\(String(describing: key)) and location:\(String(describing: location))")


        let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://yala-2018.firebaseio.com/").child("Users").child(key)

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (DataSnapshot) in


            if let dictionary = DataSnapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let user = Users()
                user.name = DataSnapshot.key


               // user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)

                user.name = dictionary["name"] as! String
                user.age = dictionary["age"] as! String
                user.sex = dictionary["sex"] as! String
                user.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profilePicUrl"] as! String
                self.users.append(user)
                print(user.name, user.age, user.profileImageUrl)
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })

            }
        })
        } else {
            print("cannot retrieve users based on location")
        }
    })

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is an incredibly inefficient interactive debugger. What happens when you run this code in a debugger? Does it ever reach the `.keyEntered` completion handler? If so, does the `key` then match what you expect? Does it then ever reach the `.value` completion handler? I so, does the `DataSnapshot.key` match the value you expect?

Comment: I had problems observeSingleEvent function. I switched it to 
    'Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://yala-2018.firebaseio.com/").child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (DataSnapshot) in' instead and it worked

Comment: Nevermind, I realized that the pathway to my database was wrong. Now it truly works